# Use one attribute with state or two attributes without state

Tags: vb.net, attributes

I'm starting to learn about custom attributes and I have one question for the more experienced users:

I want to mark my properties as "TypeA" or "TypeB" with attributes, so I can check them with reflection. Is it better to have only one attribute with state, like this:

```
Public Class FlavourAttribute
Inherits Attribute

Private _flavour As Flavours

Public ReadOnly Property Flavour() As Flavours
    Get
        Return _flavour
    End Get
End Property

Public Enum Flavours
    Sweet = 0
    Acid = 1
End Enum

Public Sub New(ByVal flavour As Flavours)
    _flavour = flavour
End Sub
```

End Class

Or is it better to use two attributes without state:

```
Public Class SweetAttribute
    Inherits Attribute
End Class

Public Class AcidAttribute
    Inherits Attribute
End Class
```

I'm asking about drawbacks of these two approaches, or possible alternatives.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not an answer to your *general* question, but the answer to your *specific* question would be to use the latter. Whether or not something is sweet is independent of whether or not it's acidic, so you're talking about different things. If, on the other hand, you were dealing with related (or mutually exclusive) properties, they should be on one attribute.

Answer (score 0):

After a while of playing with custom attributes I would say I've discovered a good reason to prefer separate attributes over one single attribute with state: it is far more simple and readable to check if one property has a single attribute than checking a property of the attribute.

Following with the example in the question, with separate attributes, we would have:

```
For Each prop As PropertyInfo In MyTipe.GetProperties
    thePropertyIsSweet= Attribute.IsDefined(prop , GetType(SweetAttribute))
    thePropertyIsAcid= Attribute.IsDefined(prop , GetType(AcidAttribute))
Next
```

While with a single attribute with state I should first check if the property has it, then cast an attribute object from it and retrieve its two properties.

I'm a wrong with this reasoning?